# What probability distribution does the Running maximum of brownian motion belong to

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I am curious to learn what distribution does the running maximum of Brownian motion 
$$ f_{M_t}(m) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}}\exp\left[-\frac{m^2}{2t}\right], \qquad m \ge 0.$$
with CDF
$$\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2 t}}\right)$$
with expectation
$$E[M_t] = \int_{0}^{\infty} m f_{M_t}(m)\,dm  = \int_{0}^{\infty} m \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}}\exp\left[-\frac{m^2}{2t}\right]\,dm = \sqrt{\frac{2t}{\pi}} $$
belong to ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem's to me that this is truncated normal, with $a=0$, $b=\infty$, and $\sigma^{2} = t$.

Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I think this is a half normal distribution, which is a special case of truncated distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution

Comment: Oh, of course. I just didn't know of that one. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$M_t$ has the same distribution as $|B_t|$, where $(B_t)$ is Brownian motion. Put another way, the distribution of $M_t$ is the  same as $\sqrt{t}|Z|$, where $Z$ has the standard normal distribution.